# How to use input variable in a stored procedure in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm creating a stored procedure which takes an input variable and does some comparison in a dynamic SQL queries. However the variable is not picked up, how can I use a variable in here. Here is how my SP looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1(
IN start_date VARCHAR(20))

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

DECLARE SQLCODE integer;
DECLARE table_exists integer default 0;
DECLARE myQuery VARCHAR(2000);

SET myQuery = "CREATE TABLE XYZ AS(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date > "+ start_date + ") WITH DATA"

execute immediate(myQuery)
END P1
```

----------REVISED ---------------

My CREATE STATEMENT is actually longer than what I've written here and I need a long VARCHAR variable myquery, but I'm getting an error that

```
``is too long.  The maximum length is "128"..``
```

What should I do?

What changes I need to make to make it work??

Comment: you can format the query as string, like myQuery = 'create.......' + start_date + ') with...' and then use it in the execute statement

Comment: to define the 'myQuery' don't I need any other keyboard?  The syntaxt is throwin an error

Comment: @uSeruSher I edited my original post based on your recommendation, but I' still facing an issue. could you have a look?

Comment: Date literals should be enclosed in single quotes, so `...WHERE date > '" || TRIM(start_date) || "')`

Comment: I'm having issues with date comparison, looks like it needs quotes but the one you suggested also doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "+" on stings in Db2. Use `||`. You were also missing some semi-colons. This code runs for me

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1(
IN start_date VARCHAR(20))

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

DECLARE SQLCODE integer;
DECLARE table_exists integer default 0;
DECLARE myQuery VARCHAR(200);

SET myQuery = 'CREATE TABLE XYZ AS(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date > '|| start_date ||') WITH DATA';

execute immediate(myQuery);
END P1
```

however you don't actually need to use dynamic SQL if you are only parameterising the date..  i.e. this also works

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1(
IN start_date DATE)

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

CREATE TABLE XYZ AS(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date > start_date) WITH DATA;

END P1
```

Still you said that you "need a long VARCHAR".. well use a CLOB and you have no practical limit

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1(
IN start_date VARCHAR(20))

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

DECLARE SQLCODE integer;
DECLARE table_exists integer default 0;
DECLARE myQuery CLOB(200000);

SET myQuery = 'CREATE TABLE XYZ AS(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date > '|| start_date ||') WITH DATA';

execute immediate(myQuery);
END P1
```

Comment: I replaced VACHAR with CLOB but still getting the same error !

Comment: Post a reproduction. You don't even show the SQL error code that you are getting.  Have you read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ? Specifically "Include just enough code to allow others to **reproduce the problem**".  Also this too https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers